# Does Donation (Daan) give Punnya if person is already having Loan on her/him?

Tags: belief, gods, bhagavad-gita, karma

If a Person regularly donates (financial donation at good place for good reason) some percentage of her/his monthly income, she/he accumulates Good Karma.

But If that person is already having some sort of financial loan on her/him like Car Loan, Home Loan, **then does she/he gets Punnya out of that donation?**

Is that Donation acceptable to Almighty God ?

Comment: Yes, but that Punya may or may not help you out of your loans :P

Comment: hahaha .. of course it may or may not be.. but important thing is person gets punnya by donation event if he has financial loan on him

Comment: ya, the law of karma doesnt stop working if a person has a loan on him :)

Comment: I've read & heard that if you do spiritual practices without paying off your debts, your punya goes to your creditor. This kinda applies to people who took sanyas without fulfilling their duties as householder e.g. people not paying the 5 debts - to rishis, pitrus, devas, manushyas & bhutas, and trying to escape their responsibilities. But nowadays in kali yuga, there is none without a long (including the guys who give you the loan), so it cancels out in a big circle. As long as you make regular payments to car/mortgage and have no intention of defrauding them, it should be fine.

Comment: @AmitSaxena I think you can provide answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the following verse from the Manu Smriti :

> Manu Smriti 11.9. (If) an opulent **man (is) liberal towards strangers,
>   while his family lives in distress,** that counterfeit virtue will first
>   make him taste the sweets (of fame, but afterwards) make him swallow
>   the poison (of punishment in hell)

Now, this verse talks about an opulent man but your question is about a man who is already in distress. So, this verse is not immediately applicable to the scenario. But it still can be adapted to your situation.

The verse means that the first duty is to look after the family. Only then one can donate to others. But , if a person is already having loans on him, implies that he and his family is in a financially distressed condition.

In that situation his first priority will be to clear the loans and make his and his family's life easy. But instead of doing that if he continues to donate then he is only adding to the financial distress he is already having and thereby neglecting his duties towards his family.

So, it will be bad karma (or mixed karma) IMO and more so because he is donating with the ulterior motive of earning punya or merits only.